# using azure functions in VS2017, cannot bind to ServiceBus Queue as an output

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I'm running Visual Studio v15.3 and trying to create an Azure Function.  I'm having trouble binding an output to a Service Bus Queue.  I get the following error when I startup:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'CreateRawTransactions.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind
>   parameter 'outputSbQueue' to type String&. Make sure the parameter
>   Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions
>   (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

My function.cs code...

```
public static class CreateRawTransactions
{
        [FunctionName("CreateRawTransactions")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, 
                                              TraceWriter log,
                                              [ServiceBus("outqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] out string outputSbQueue)
        {
          outputSbQueue = "Hello ";
        }  
}
```

and the function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "outputSbQueue",
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "queueName": "testqueue",
      "connection": "ServiceBusConnection",
      "direction": "out",
      "accessRights": "listen"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false

}
```

and the local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ServiceBusConnection": "Endpoint=sb://..."

  }
}
```

As an update, I changed the input trigger from an HttpTrigger to a ServiceBusTrigger and it works.  Seems like it is something to do with using an HttpTrigger.

Comment: Possibly the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005865/error-with-azure-function-service-bus-output-binding) ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/1804, and has been fixed. If you get an updated CLI, it should work.